# .NET MAUI - HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" is not working on Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui, text-alignment

I've converted a project from Xamarin to .Net MAUI. MAUI has many issues, but one of the most annoying is the fact that `HorizontalTextAlignment` set to `Center` is not working in Android. For labels that are only a single line the regular HorizontalAlignment is working, but for multiple line labels it is not a working solution:

[image]

In the screenshot the two header labels are centered using HorizontalAlignment on the VisualElement, but for the longer text below this is not working. Event though the label element is centered, the text inside is not center aligned.

Does anyone have a solution?

P.S. `HorizontalTextAlignment` is working in iOS, and it is also working in my Android emulator when I manipulate it in Hot Reload.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11251

Comment: That worked! Can't believe I didn't stumble across this in my search for an answer. Thank you!

Comment: You can post your answer as it will help others who have similar issue. If you don't mind, I can help you do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue because I upgraded a xamarin project to Maui. Somehow in the android mainifest the value android:supportsRtl="true" is then not set on the application element like this:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="YourAppName" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Thanks to @ewerspej